# About DHCP behavior?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [What ports does DHCP typically use other than 67 & 68](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52652/what-ports-does-dhcp-typically-use-other-than-67-68)

Hello,

Could you give more reasons why asking more details about the DHCP is off-topic? I have been observing lots of DHCP logs connecting to devices over SMB ports and the DHCP servers are also being flagged for sending out excessive DNS requests. I have done my research to understand if this is a normal behavior for DHCP when data centers are migrated, but I really did not find any appropriate site answering my questions. Please consider this and clarify my question. It will be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: DHCP is an application-layer protocol (above OSI layer-4). In the **Off-Topic** section of the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, it says, "_protocols above L4 in the OSI model (e.g. HTTP, FTP, etc);_"  _[RFC 2131, Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2131)_ is the definition for DHCP. Search the RFC for `port` and you will find your answer.